# How to throttle MongoDB write operations on one shard

Tags: mongodb

We have a sharded MongoDB Cluster. One of our biggest collections is sharded based on the document id.

During some occasions, the interactions on one document increase a lot, and then because of this, we get the `MongoDBLockQueueBacklogging` error which brings the whole cluster down.

We don't really need those interactions to be persisted in real-time, we can throttle them for some milliseconds.

I was reading about the Kafka-MongoDB connector, and it sounds like a very good idea. The problem is we cannot use update operators (`$inc`, `$current_date`, etc.) with it.

I have a feeling that there is something already for such a problem but I cannot find it (or I am not searching correctly)

Comment: Can you reference your statement about needed to use "$inc, $current_date etc" ... as far as I read about , mongodb connector is also recommended by mongodb to mongodb replication using changeStream... if you can refer and explain more about your concerns regarding the connector maybe I could assist more

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/kafka-connector/current/kafka-sink/
I cannot find any way to use those operators inside this documentation :(

Comment: My idea about the connector was that I can write a lot of update queries to MongoDB. 
But What I figure out, the connector is way to write documents and not update/insert queries

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly,  it works on whole document level

Comment: You mean, the shard key is `_id`? This would be a poor choice, see [Monotonically Changing Shard Keys](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-choose-a-shard-key/#monotonically-changing-shard-keys). Better use `sh.shardCollection( "db.collection", { _id : "hashed" } )` In Mongo version 5.0 you can [Reshard a Collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-reshard-a-collection/)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit this is what we are using

Comment: @D.SM How can I throttle the writing to the collection to mitigate  `MongoDBLockQueueBacklogging`